# Is there a 5-cell-600-cell honeycomb?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, polytopes

Is there a convex uniform tiling of hyperbolic 4-space with 5-cells and 600-cells as its facets and a snub 24-cell as its vertex figure?

Comment: The icosahedron {3,5} allows for a symmetrical 4-coloring of its vertices, such that the removal of one such set transforms it into the tridiminished icosahedron with faces being triangles and pentagons. The hexacosachoron {3,3,5} allows for a symmetrical 5-coloring of its vertices, such that the removal of one such transforms it into the snub icositetrachoron with cells being tetrahedra and icosahedra. - Thus your quest asks for the existance of the next-dimensional analogue, then for sure within hyperbolic space, i.e. a corresponding 6-coloring of the vertices of {3,3,3,5}.